# Unable to select model argument for urdf-tutorial package

Tags: ros, roslaunch, urdf-tutorial, find-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm looking into the tutorials on URDF (ROS Indigo), robot_state_publisher etc. In [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) tutorial it is stated that

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

should start `rviz` (launch parameters stored inside `display.launch`) with the selected model. Sadly I'm getting the error that such file cannot be found:

```
rosuser:~$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
... logging to /home/rosuser/.ros/log/336d620e-8d02-11e5-b0c5-90fba64806be/roslaunch-latadmin-ros-7550.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 298, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 260, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 209, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 124, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 730, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 702, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 646, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 264, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 463, in param_value
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

I also read the lines below:

> This launch file assumes that
> 01-myfirst.urdf is in the urdf
> subdirectory of the directory that you
> type the command in. Otherwise, you
> should say model:='$(find
> pkg-name)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf' where
> pkg-name is the name of the package
> that the file is in (single quotes
> required)

I tried both with an installed version of the package and a fresh download of the package inside my `catkin workspace` but in both cases I'm getting the same error. I have checked and the `urdf` folder is there along with the specified file (last line of the following terminal output):

```
rosuser:/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf_tutorial$ ls -R
.:
cmake  images  launch  package.xml  urdf  urdf.rviz  urdf.vcg

./cmake:
urdf_tutorialConfig-version.cmake  urdf_tutorialConfig.cmake

./images:
flexible.png  materials.png  multipleshapes.png  myfirst.png  origins.png  visual.png

./launch:
display.launch  gazebo.launch  xacrodisplay.launch

./urdf:
01-myfirst.urdf  02-multipleshapes.urdf  03-origins.urdf  04-materials.urdf  05-visual.urdf  06-flexible.urdf  07-physics.urdf  08-macroed.urdf.xacro  r2d2.xacro
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? I've looked into the `launch` file and from what my poor knowledge on the topic tells me is that it should be working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221050/unable-to-select-model-argument-for-urdf-tutorial-package/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-17**:
Please add the exact error message to your original post (use the *edit* button/link). Also: which version of ROS, how installed, etc.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-11-17**:
Done, although the error message doesn't say much (even by looking at the trace) and also I don't get the "how installed" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> rosuser:~$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
> [..]
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
> ```

according to this, you are invoking `roslaunch` from your home directory (`~`). As the tutorial explains:

> This launch file assumes that `01-myfirst.urdf` is in the `urdf` subdirectory of the directory **that you type the command in**.

While the wording could be a bit better, it essentially tells you that you can only give `display.launch` a *relative path* to `01-myfirst.urdf` if you are actually in a directory that is the *direct parent* of the `urdf` directory.

Your home directory is not the direct parent of the `/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf_tutorial/urdf` directory, hence the error.

Either do a `roscd urdf_tutorial` before trying to launch `display.launch` or use the alternative way to launch it (change `pkg-name` to `urdf_tutorial`):

> Otherwise, you should say `model:='$(find pkg-name)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'` where `pkg-name` is the name of the package that the file is in (single quotes required)

This form should work no matter what your current working directory is.

---

edit: I've changed the wording of the quoted section of the tutorial to be more clear about relative vs absolute paths to files in the `urdf_tutorial` package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1